# How to display custom text from attribute after product title on product page

Tags: magento2

How to display custom text from attribute after product title on product page
Currently, I have created a custom .phtml file and displayed text before the product title:

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.col.info">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.before.title" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/before_title.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

> before_title.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$custom = $_product->getData('brand');

?>

<!--<//?= $custom ?> -->
<div class="brand-name-title"> <?php 
            $optionText = '';
            $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand');

            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
               $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getBrand());
            }
            ?>
            <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                 <?php echo "" . $optionText . "<br>"; ?>
            <?php } ?></div>
```

This is working correct:
[image]

Now I am trying to display custom text from attribute `subname` after the title using another phtml template file (below the title).

> after_title.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$custom = $_product->getData('subname');

?>

<!--<//?= $custom ?> -->
<div class="subname-name"> <?php 
            $optionText = '';
            $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('subname');

            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
               $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getSubname());
            }
            ?>
            <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                 <?php echo "" . $optionText . "<br>"; ?>
            <?php } ?></div>
```

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.col.info">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.after.title" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/after_title.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But here in this case I didn't get the text displayed after the title on product pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your template in XML layout file before `</body>` tag as below.

> File: catalog_product_view.xml

```
<body>
    ...
    <referenceContainer name="content.top.most">
        <container name="custom.block.subname" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-product-subname" before="-">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom_subname" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/after_title.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

I have tested this and got the content below the product title on product pages.

Hope this will help you!

**===== UPDATE =====**

Add below code after your `<body>` tag in your XML layout file. To move your `after_title.phtml` template file content after product title.

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<body>
    <move element="custom.block.subname" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title"/>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: I dont know why, but  I also try in your way but impossible display this. You can check in: https://nansy.pl/alien.html also  you can check container https://nansy.pl/alien.html?ath=1 with shift in console.

Comment: I've display 2 times "brand" above title and under title from before_title and after_title but this after title no dsiplayed. I also try only echo test

Comment: Your template file is called on the product page. I can see your echo test before the title. SS: https://nimb.ws/MUmVcy

Comment: Please check my updates in the above answer. I have added the code to move your template file content below the product title.

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I resolve this  in this way <referenceContainer name="box.inner1">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.after.title" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/after_title.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer> with some css custom code