# Display Custom attribute value on PDP Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.2-p1, magento2.4.3.p1

I want to display custom product attribute value on PDP Page just below the product name. How that can be achieved, please guide.
Rashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding block and phtml file

Follow the link :
[How to display custom text from attribute after product title on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350434/how-to-display-custom-text-from-attribute-after-product-title-on-product-page)

Answer (score 2):

To call the custom attribute follow the below steps:

1. Add this code in Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml file and changed the name and its code.

---

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block name="product.custom.attributes" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom-attribute.phtml" after="page.main.title">
    <arguments>
    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDemoLink</argument>
    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">customAttribute</argument>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">customAttribute</argument>
    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Custom Attribute</argument>
    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="customAttribute"</argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>
    
    </referenceContainer>
```

---

2. Create a template file in Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom-attribute.phtml and add this code and change the attribute name.

---

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <div class="custom-attribute">
        <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?>
            <strong class="type"><?php echo $_attributeLabel?></strong>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>>
            <?php echo $_attributeValue; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked